# Does @NonNullApi covers static methods?

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, spring-data

I put `@org.springframework.lang.NonNullApi` annotation on my `package-info.java` for repository interfaces.

```java
@NonNullApi
package ....jpa.repository;
```

And IntellJ IDEA is telling that a parameter(or an argument) in my `static` methods don't needed to be checked.

```java
final class RepositoryUtil {

    static void doSome(final CriteriaBuidler builder) {
        if (builder == null) { // <<-- right here!!!
            throw new NullPointerException("builder is null");
        }
    }
}
```

IntelliJ IDEA tells me

> Parameter 'builder' inherits container annotation, thus 'non-null`

Is it telling me the truth?

Answer (score 1):

Yep.

According to the documentation, `@NonNullApi` is "a common Spring annotation to declare that parameters and return values are to be considered as non-nullable by default for a given package."

If `RepositoryUtil` is part of the package you annotated with `@NonNullApi`, its parameters and return values (obviously meaning the parameters and return values of its methods) will be non-nullable and so checking for null would be redundant.

If the `builder` parameter can actually be null, you can annotate it with `@Nullable` to override the package default you established with `@NonNullApi`.

Answer (score 1):

I tested for myself

```
static String s1(Object object) {
    if (object == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("object is null");
    }
    return object.toString();
}

default String i1(Object object) {
    if (object == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("object is null");
    }
    return object.toString();
}
```

With my `@SpringBootTest` class,

When I do `.s1(null)`, I got `NullPointerException` thrown.

When I do `.i1(null)`, I got,

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter object in SomeProductRepository.i1 must not be null!

Which drives me to conclude that `static` methods don't count.

Comment: What object are you calling `.i1(null)` on, and how did you define it? It's probably an instance of some generated class that is wrapping the class you wrote and throwing the `IllegalArgumentException`.

Comment: What IntelliJ IDEA tells you, and what your class actually does, are two different things. Just annotating a method doesn't cause it to perform a null check or throw an exception. It is a signal to *other* components, like IDEA and Spring, to flag attempts to call the method with null as an error. It looks like IDEA considers the annotation to apply to static methods (which would be consistent with the annotation documentation) but that Spring doesn't actually implement null checks for static methods, which is not surprising, as they cannot be overridden in a generated wrapper class.